# SQL JOIN and count without counting an ID twice

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join a table and get a count but I cannot count an ID twice in the table for the count.

Table 1:

```
ID animal
-- ------
 1    dog
 2    dog
 3    cat
 4    cat
 5    dog
```

Table 2:

```
ID
--
 2
 2
 3
 5
 5
```

I need to get a count of how many of each type of animal are in table 2. I can get it to join and change the ID to the type of animal and then get a count of each.

The issue is that each ID can only get counted once. So the expected output would be.

```
dog:2
cat:1
```

Where my output is

```
dog:4
cat:1
```

Comment: Table 2 has no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or Sqlite?

Comment: You missed SQL Server in the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below

```
select t1.animal, count( distinct t2.ID) 
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
group by t1.animal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `count distinct id`

```
select b.animal,count(distinct a.id) from table2 a
inner join table1 b on a.id=b.id
group by b.animal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.animal AS "Animal", COUNT(DISTINCT t1.ID) AS "No. of Animals"
FROM TABLE2 t2, TABLE1 t1
WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.animal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Nested Selects here.

```
SELECT 
t.animal, 
COUNT(t.ID) AS Count
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT a.animal, b.ID FROM table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID)t
GROUP BY t.animal
```

[this is tested image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s83Fl.png)